# How to force a version conflict in iCloud

Tags: conflict, icloud

I have a working implementation of iCloud. Now I want to improve conflict handling by adding some merge functionality. I've been trying to come up with a consistent way of forcing a conflict for testing purposes but I haven't had luck so far, conflicts don't occur consistently when I expect them to occur. This might indicate that I'm doing something wrong, or maybe that I just misunderstood something about how iCloud works (yet another thing, I mean).

I'm using UIDocument and yes, I'm listening to the UIDocumentStateChangedNotification. In fact, I do get some occasional conflict notifications. Also, I only have one file in iCloud.

Having two devices using the same iCloud accout, here is the flow of events I was expecting to always cause a conflict:

- Open the file on both devices (both devices are now correctly seeing the same content). *Note:* Here is the only time openWithCompletionHandler is called, after this it's never called again.
- Make some change on device A and call saveToURL.
- Wait some time to allow the change to propagate.
- Make some other change on device B and call saveToURL.
- Wait some time to allow the change to propagate.
- **EXPECTED:** The app should be getting a conflict notification from iCloud. **OBSERVED:** A conflict does occur very occasionally, but most of the time what happens is simply that the UIDocument gets its UIDocumentStateEditingDisabled flag set and then cleared back after half a second or so (I'd guess editing is being disabled while the iCloud daemon is pulling the version from the other device and saving it in the local ubiquitous directory).

Much like a version control system like SVN, I was expecting the version from device B to cause a conflict because an "update" was required in order to get the version uploaded by device A.

Am I wrong expecting a conflict in the scenario I just described? Why? Is there any other way to consistently force a conflict?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would have thought a better way to cause a conflict would be to:

- Make sure both devices have an up-to-date copy of the data
- Put both devices into Airplane Mode to prevent any iCloud updates
- Change the data in the same place on both devices, each with different new data
- Turn the network back on
- Wait for the changes to propagate

[From the docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW13)

> Conflicts occur when two instances of an app change a file locally and both changes are then transferred to iCloud. For example, this can happen when the changes are made while the device is in Airplane mode and cannot transmit changes to iCloud right away. When it does happen, iCloud stores both versions of the file and notifies the apps’ file presenters that a conflict has occurred and needs to be resolved.

The way you are doing it (allowing time for sync, altering the documents differently) seems like it *shouldn't* cause a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud works basically the same as version control system - except that you can only access the conflict versions (when conflict happens).

When a device pulled `ver_1` from iCloud, edit, save, and find the server has a different version (`ver_2` or newer) than it expected, a conflicted version will be created.

After the initial sync, you can:

1. turn off wifi on device B, edit & save.
2. edit on device A, save.
3. turn on wifi on device B.

A conflict will come soon.